# how to output a 3 by 3 array to Seaborn chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

this is more of a data visualisation issue. I got a 3 by 3 output from my calculations and I want to project the output on to a Seaborn chart for better visual effect. How do I do that? I have attached a random pic of how ideally I would like to see it below. Numbers inside the individual squares will be from my 3*3 array to be clear.

```
Hypothetical 3*3 array
opt = np.random.randint(1,10,9).reshape(3,3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [seaborn.heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html). Beyond providing `data` (2D array), set `annot=True` if you wish cells to be labeled, simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
data = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
ax = sns.heatmap(data, annot=True)
```

gives
[image: seaborn heatmap]

Comment: thanks that is what I wanted. One more question - how do I rename the axis? for instance if on x-axis I wanted 0,1,2 replaced by say <5, 5-10,>10. likewise on y-axis replacing by  >-5, -5 - -10, <-10.

Comment: @TRex provide names list using `xticklabels` and `yticklabels`, for example if you replace last line in my example using `ax = sns.heatmap(data, annot=True, xticklabels=['A','B','C'], yticklabels=['X','Y','Z'])` you will get columns A, B, C and rows X, Y, Z